# Token for Field Collection values

Tags: tokens, entities

I have a node that has a field created with Field Collection module.
Field is composed of 3 subfields: dropdown list and 2 text boxes.

I want to get values from those 3 fields in my Rule.

How would I reference those fields?

I have installed Advanced Entity Tokens module.

thx!

Answer (score 3):

Solved! There is a list of all available tokens in: admin/help/token.

In my case I needed to get 3 field values from Field Collection:

```
[node:field-school-undergrad:0:field-school-list]
[node:field-school-undergrad:0:field-school-degree]
[node:field-school-undergrad:0:field-school-year]
```

Comment: This works well to display one specific set of values for a field collection but I need this token to be dynamic. I tried [node:field-school-undergrad:item-id:field-school-list] (with my own fields, of course) but it did not work. Is there a token to call for all field collection values for one field in this collection?